# Submit GridView rows back to database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have this C# Code:

```
using (ContractorsEntities context = new ContractorsEntities(Properties.Settings.Default.Connection))
        {
            warningBindingSource.DataSource = context.Warnings.ToList();
            educationLevelBindingSource.DataSource = context.EducationLevels.ToList();
            penaltyBindingSource.DataSource = context.Penalties.ToList();
        }
```

Everything is working fine without any problems but if I add new rows to GridView or updated some rows for example, how i can submit data - new rows - to Database?

I know we should call `context.SaveChanges();` but it will not work.

Comment: Have you tried calling context.SaveChanges() and it didn't work?

Comment: @Circular Reference Actually no because `context` will get disposed after returning all data from database.

Comment: I think you need a shared context here.

Comment: @CircularReference according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264983/entity-framework-objectcontext-share-pros-and-cons sharing context is bad

Comment: UnitOfWork is essentially a layer or abstraction so you can share your context properly.

Comment: I've done a bit more digging, apparently it is a good idea to use a single context per form : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392

Answer (score 0):

Use Context.Warnings.Local.ToBindingList()  to do the binding